# MYSQL: Return all rows in one table along with the sum of matching rows in another

Tags: mysql, join

EDIT - I apologize but I didn't include the correct information the first time!

I have the following two tables:

```
table 1
+----+-------+-------+
| id | model | color |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | 111AA | red   |
|  2 | 222BB | blue  |
|  3 | 333CC |       |
|  4 | 444DD | green |
+----+-------+-------+

table 2
+----+-------+-------+
| id | model | quant |
+----+-------+-------+
|  6 | 111AA |     2 |
|  7 | 222BB |     5 |
|  8 | 222BB |     3 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

I need a query that will take all the rows from table 1 where the color column is not empty along with the sum of the column quantity in table two that match a certain model (in the example given, model = '222BB') to produce the following table:

```
+----+-------+-------+------+
| id | model | color | quant|
+----+-------+-------+------+
|  1 | 111AA | red   |      |
|  2 | 222BB | blue  |    8 |
|  4 | 444DD | green |      |
+----+-------+-------+------+
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.model, t1.color, SUM(t2.quant) 
FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.color != '' AND t2.model = '222BB'
```

However, this didn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a pretty basic query with a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Can you please explain why there is no entry for red ?

Comment: @Jigar - because I only want the quantities listed for a particular model.  Other models should have an empty quantity column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive the expected table, run the following SQL query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.model, t1.color, IF(t2.model = '222BB', SUM(t2.quant), NULL) 
  FROM table1 t1 
   LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.model = t2.model 
  WHERE t1.color != '' 
  GROUP BY t1.model
```

The result will be the same as in your table. But I think it would be better to update the design to make join on ID column but not model-name.

Comment: This seems to work the best.  I still can't get the quantity to sum correctly - they are all showing 'NULL'.  It looks like my IF clause if always returning false for some reason.

Comment: It is strange. Can you please provide what you try to use in IF condition as model(concern you dump example)?

Answer (score 0):

In Sql, you should not write != or == with null. It is highly suggested that you use **IS NULL** and **IS NOT NULL** clause.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-null-values.htm

** select a.model,b.total from  (select model from table1 where color is not null) a, (select model,sum(quant) total from table2 group by model) b where a.model=b.model;
**

Comment: I tried changing the != to IS NOT NULL but I am still getting the same result, which is just one row with this entry:  |  2 | 222BB | blue  |    8 |

Comment: @paul if you append **t2.model = '222BB'**, it will return you only one record. Additionally, you should use **sum** clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select t1.id, t1.model,t1.color,sum(t2.quant)
from table1 t1
   left outer join table2 t2 on (t1.model = t2.model and t1.color <> ‘’)
group by t1.model
```